# Issue with adding multiple objects to Core Data (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

**OverView**

I continue to run into issues with adding multiple values to my Core Data entity. All i need to do is simply add 6 string-value items from a text field into Core Data. Specific examples/critique of my code would be very appreciated, as i am nearing mental break down with this issue.

**The Issue**

The first time i ran this, i tested it by saving only the first line (the product name) to core data and then printing it off. It worked perfect. After that, i tried the same method for all of them, and then tried printing. My program would set a breakpoint next to the "entity1.setValue(three, forKey: "serialNo")."

I also get a message in the debugger area that says (lldb).
If i try to step through the breakpoint, everything just prints out as 'nil'.

**CODE**

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let entity1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("UsedInfo", inManagedObjectContext:context) as NSManagedObject
    let one = pickerTextField.text
    let two = modelName.text
    let three = serialNo.text
    let four = YOM.text
    let five = engineHours.text
    let six = locationOfMachine.text

    entity1.setValue(one, forKey: "product")
    entity1.setValue(two, forKey:"modelName")
    entity1.setValue(three, forKey:"serialNo")
    entity1.setValue(four, forKey:"yom")
    entity1.setValue(five, forKey:"engineHours")
    entity1.setValue(six, forKey:"location")
    print(entity1.valueForKey("product"))
    print(entity1.valueForKey("modelName"))
    print(entity1.valueForKey("serialNo"))
    print(entity1.valueForKey("yom"))
    print(entity1.valueForKey("engineHours"))


    do {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }


}
```

Comment: What issues have you been running into?

Comment: I'm sorry! I rushed the post a little too much! I'll edit it!

Comment: Having seen [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923636/saving-an-integer-in-core-data), I suggest you follow the advice given there about creating subclasses of `NSManagedObject` first, and then come back to this problem.